# What is the format of .virtualenvs for pyvenv-workon

Tags: virtualenv

In my `~/.virtualenvs` file, I have:

```bash
WORKON_HOME=/where/my/venvs/are/venv/
```

Emacs cannot find `WORKON_HOME` and cannot find my `virtualenvs`.  What is the correct format of this file?

Comment: Emacs doesn’t read your `.virtualenvs` file. Emacs might in some modes run other programs which do read that file, in which case you should read the documentation of those other programs.

Comment: Did you install virtualenvwrapper as described [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/). Additionally, you could have a look at the Spacemacs instructions for pyvenv: https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/python/README.html#manage-virtual-environments-with-pyvenv.

Comment: Yes, I did.  But I don't know what should be contained in the .virtualenvs file.